# Google Calendar v3: Access Not Configured

Tags: javascript, calendar

Im using javascript version of this and have this code

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
             'calendarId': 'idofmycalendar@group.calendar.google.com'});
        request.execute(function(resp) {console.log(resp);});
});
```

all are OK (i guess) and i made the calendar public too. But i always get the "Access Not Configured" error. same if i make the calendarId to primary... any idea on what i missed here? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Google Calendar service using the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

(Dupe of /q/13863500/)